# Query with "ORDER BY" in php does not provide accurate results

Tags: php, mysql

i have this query in my php

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY btn_id" ;
    foreach ($PDO->query($sql) as $row) 
    {
      echo '<tr>
                 <td>$row['btn_id']</td>
                 <td>$row['description']</td>
            </tr>';
    }
?>
```

the output goes like this:

```
Button ID | Description
1         | Assessment
10        | Registration
11        | Payroll
2         | Loan
3         | Sample
```

It sorts by the first digit instead of the whole number. That's why all the values with the same digits appear first. Order by inaccurately through the first digit it has.

Comment: It looks like your `btn_id` column is a character type. I'd recommend changing it to a numeric type (e.g., `INT`) if it's not too late. If you can't change it then `ORDER BY CAST(btn_id AS UNSIGNED)`.

Comment: it's already an int but still it has error.

Comment: If it's an int, you will not be getting that sort order. If it's not an int altering the table as suggesting or ORDER BY btn_id+0 as in my answer works. The only conclusion that can be reached is that you haven't shared your actual code.

Comment: thank you! I already solved my problem and my problem is about the structure of the <table> in php. Surprisingly, it's about the css.

Comment: pretty hard to see how CSS can effect sorting. Please update your question to show the CSS that you have actually applied here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your **btn_id column** is a character type. So i recommend you to change the data type to integer.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_buttons MODIFY btn_id INT
```

you can alter the column data type this way.
if you are not able to alter the table then use like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY CAST(btn_id AS UNSIGNED)
```

And your php code will be like

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY CAST(btn_id AS UNSIGNED) ;" ;
    foreach ($PDO->query($sql) as $row) 
    {
      echo '<tr>
                 <td>$row['btn_id']</td>
                 <td>$row['description']</td>
            </tr>';
    }
?>
```

Please try this way.This will work in your case.

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY btn_id ASC please try this way? Is this giving the same issue in your case.?

Comment: @MigsMartin please come in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129774/chat-about-mysql-error

Comment: i can't talk because i need to have 20 reputation for me to talk.

this is my table query: 

create table tbl_button (
btn_id int(11) not null,
description varchar(100) not null)

Comment: where is your table structure ?

Comment: i selected it in my php file, like this:

select * from tbl_buttons Order by btn_id

Comment: try this too ORDER BY CAST(btn_id AS UNSIGNED)

Comment: Your suggestion worked when i used it in phpmyadmin or in cmd mode of xampp. But when I tried to insert it in the php code. It doesn't seem to work. Perhaps, using dataTable affects the arrangement of the data?

Comment: may be.. that is also a reason

Comment: thank you! I already solved my problem and my problem is about the structure of the <table> in php. Surprisingly, it's about the css. But i think your query would be of much help to me later.

Comment: Always welcome. if you think this is helpful please up vote the ans and accept it. Then it is useful to others also. Thank you.

Comment: God Bless you brother :) i wish you can help more people like me.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have stored your btn_ids in a char or varchar column. Since it appears to be integer data, you should convert that to int.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_buttons MODIFY btn_id INT
```

A lesser solution is to modify your query as follows

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_buttons ORDER BY btn_id+0
```

This would result in the btn_id field being automatically cast to int. The reason that this is inferior is because there is extra work for the server and the query planner maybe unable to use an index on btn_id if one exists. And integer data should always be saved in INT fields.